# The Bootstrap service is not found - after computer name change

Tags: wonderware

**Error: Failed to deploy COMPUTER_NAME :The Bootstrap service is not found on remote machine**

Hello Stack overflow users. Google yields no results...

I configured a Wonderware Intouch for System Platform Runtime Client remote computer according to best practices found in the README files and other documentation.

On the GR in the ArchestrA IDE I created a platform then a view-engine and then an instance of the Intouch app underneath that.
I successfully deployed the application to the remote computer and everything was working as expected.

Afterwards I had to change the remote computer name as per our policy because the computer would be used at another site.
First I undeployed everything including the platform from the remote runtime computer. Then I changed the remote runtime computer name. Then I renamed all the objects in the IDE on the GR accordingly and changed the computer host name in the platform object instance accordingly.
I then tried to deploy the platform again, no success, I only receive an error message:

> *"Error: Failed to deploy COMPUTER_NAME :The Bootstrap service is not found on remote machine"*

[image: The error message I receive.]

I have tried:
 - Restarting the computer.
 - Changing the IP Address.
 - Google and AVEVA Knowledge base.
 - Platform removal tool (which cannot be accessed since the platform does not display in the SMC manager)

The version of System Platform is 2014 R2 SP1.

When I look in the SMC log file, the Bootstrap service is starting on the remote runtime client.

[image: SMC Log File]

I am not to keen to format the computer and start over so I would like to know if there may be some files that I need to delete or something else I could do to fix this problem.

**EDIT:**
I have also as mentioned in the comments and additionally tried:
 - Uninstall Wonderware completely followed by a new fresh Install.

Comment: I remember having to do it on SP2012 years ago. Even with fairly clear description from a colleague (super-expert) it was still long and painful process, involving direct sql changes in few places in the GR DB, and in some config files, it felt almost like a hack. If you don't have access to such colleague, I'd recommend just uninstall and reinstall whole SP.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the uninstall re-install route and see if that resolves the problem. At least that is a little less work than formatting the entire computer.

Comment: @9953-div-37 how you make out? I remember troubleshooting this and recall using a mix of ArchestrA's logs, and Window's Logs to determine there's often problems either with hostname resolution or DCOM access permissions. Usually you can tease out enough info to search AVEVA's support page for more detailed info on a specific error. EDIT: make sure you check logs on both the Galaxy and Deploy target computers

Comment: @Grambot I have done the un-install and re-install of the Wonderware products but that did not work. I suspect that there may be something in the registry that needs to be removed. I have since formatted the PC and created a new platform instance to deploy the app again. If I get time I will setup another PC and reproduce the problem to test and see. I also suspect it has something to do with platform IDs. Thank you for the help and input so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem recently. The problem seems to be that when creating a platform in the IDE it associates an ID for it and if you change the name of the machine and change the name of the platform it can try to search for the old platform through the id. To solve this, create a new platform and try to deploy it, System Platform can associate an old ID with the new platform, then create platforms until you have a unique id not yet used and deploy it. The platform id can be verified in the SMC. When deploying, leave the SMC open next to the IDE and note the ID of the platform being deployed.

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually makes sense! I will definitely try this.